# asterisk: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libasteriskssl.so.1 After Installation of Asterisk 11.9.0

Tags: asterisk

I have installed Asterisk 11.9.0, but when i try to start the Asterisk instance, i get this error:

```
[root@localhost]# asterisk -rvvvv
asterisk: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libasteriskssl.so.1: undefined symbol: _ast_mem_backtrace_buffer
```

I tried to search online, but could not find any explanation to this error. I would really appreciate if someone guide me in this regard, i am using Centos 6.x :
2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

```
[root@localhost]#  ldd /usr/sbin/asterisk
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe89ff000)
    libasteriskssl.so.1 => /usr/lib/libasteriskssl.so.1 (0x00007f302092e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003652400000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x000000365d800000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003653800000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003653400000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x0000003669c00000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003662800000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x000000365f000000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003652800000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003652c00000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f302070a000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000003654400000)
    libedit.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0 (0x00007f30204da000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x000000365e800000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003652000000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x000000365f800000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x000000365e400000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x000000365e000000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x000000365f400000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f30202cd000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x000000365ec00000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003654000000)
```

Looking forward to your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have remove all duplicates for libssl, if any

After that need install libssl-devel and recompile asterisk with your version of library.